# fs readfile not read all file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, next.js, node.js-fs

fs readfile not read all file in nodejs

use nextjs 13, is there any solution for this ?

code

```
 const image = await fs.readFile(filepath);
 const body = new FormData();
 const blob = new Blob([image]);
 body.append('file', blob);
 console.log(body.getAll('file'));
```

what I get

```
[
  File { size: 21566, type: '', name: 'blob', lastModified: 1702548191951 }
]
```

expected

```
[
  File {
    path: "100%authentic-bg-2x.png"
    preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/e4311e6e-519d-4e03-9735-22a9dbebc4b0"
    lastModified: 1691749934331
    lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 11 2023 17:32:14 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time) {}
    name: "100%authentic-bg-2x.png"
    size: 21566
    type: "image/png"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const FormData = require('form-data');
const path = require('path');


async function uploadFile(filepath) {
  try {
    // Read the file content
    const image = await fs.readFile(filepath);

    // Create a FormData object
    const body = new FormData();

    // Convert the file content to a Buffer and append it to the FormData
    const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(image);
    body.append('file', fileBuffer, {
      filename: path.basename(filepath),
      contentType: 'image/png',
    });

    // Log the FormData details
    console.log(body.getAll('file'));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading file:', error);
  }
}

const filepath = 'path/to/your/image.png';

// Call the function to upload the file
uploadFile(filepath);
```

- I changed `new Blob([image])` to `Buffer.from(image)` because it's a simpler way to handle file content.
- I added options directly when calling `append` to make it clear that we're setting the filename and contentType for the file being appended.
- Remember to replace 'path/to/your/image.png' with the actual path to your image file.

Hope this will work for you...